# Android Extra White Space in Tool Bar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar, removing-whitespace

I am trying to brainstorm some ideas as to why my toolbar has extra whitespace at the top. I have confirmed through logging that during onResume() the paddingTop and marginTop are set to 0dp yet I am receiving the following:

[image]

My code for the toolbar is as such:
[image]

I am setting the padding and margin top to 0 in the fragment's onResume() as such:

[image]

Already spent too much time on this UI bug and still not sure what else could be causing the extra whitespace, any idea is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can you confirm once- Which Parent Theme you are using in style.xml?

Comment: @SandeshKhutalSaheb Hello I am using ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light as the parent theme for the toolbar

Comment: Then change it with-  ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar and try once